# Laravel eloquent - where field is equal to one of 2 values

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to make a query in Laravel project with which I would fetch the record in the DB that would have a slug equal to `post` or `page`:

```
where('slug', 'post' || 'page')
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why can't  you use whereIn('slug', ['post', 'page'])?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `orWhere` you can do it like this:

```
->where('slug','page')
->orWhere('slug','post')
```

Another way is,

```
->whereIn('slug',['post','page']);
```

Another way

```
->whereRaw("slug = 'post' or slug = 'page'")
```